# python import with absolute path

Tags: python

I have the following folder structure and want to find a good way to import python modules.

```
project1/test/benchmark/benchmark_project1.py

#in benchmark_project1.py
from project1.test.benchmark import *
```

My question is how to get rid of `project1`, since it might be renamed to "`project2`" or something else. I want to use `import` with absolute path, but don't know a good way to achieve that.

Comment: You might want to look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55173115/reading-resource-files-in-python#comment97085457_55173115 specifically  Michael Butscher's comment

Answer (score 0):

You can use `os.chdir()` to change your directory before the import statement, and then to change it back afterward. This will allow you to specify the precise file to import. You can use `os.listdir()` to get the list of all files in the directory, and then simply index them. Using a loop will get all the modules in the folder, or providing the right index according to some pattern will give you a specific one. The glob module allows you to select files using regex.

```py
import os

cwd = os.getcwd()

new_dir = 'project1/test/benchmark/'
list_dir = os.listdir(new_dir) # Find all matching

os.chdir(new_dir)
for i in range(len(list_dir)): # Import all of them (or index them in some way)
    module = list_dir[i][0:-3] # Filter off the '.py' file extension
    from module import *
os.chdir(cwd)
```

Alternatively, you can add the location to your path instead of changing directories. Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder) for some additional resources.